# Using ellipsis in main method?

Tags: java

If i use ellipsis in main method would it make any difference?

```
public static void main(String... args) {

}
```

Comment: yes .. it worked.. but i just want to know.. is this also a valid approach..?

Comment: Nat Pryce's take on this: http://natpryce.com/articles/000708.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No difference. That "ellipsis" syntax is called [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html), whose parameter type is actually an array.

This means there are actually *three* possible signatures of a valid `main()` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {}
public static void main(String... args) {}
public static void main(String args[]) {}
```

Comment: And the reason behind this is that the compiler interprets `T...` as `T[]`.

Answer (score 4):

It does not make any difference, since the JVM turns the ellipsis (also called "varargs") into an array at "compile" time:

```
void myMethod(final X... args)
```

is exactly the same as

```
void myMethod(final X[] args)
```

or (less frequent)

```
void myMethod(final X args[])
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `X[]` is more common than `args[]` and, in my opinion, strongly preferred as well (`args` is a type of `X[]`, not `X`). Are you sure put the last two in the right order?

Answer (score 2):

It is the same. Given the following class files:

```
$ cat MainEllipsis.java
public class MainEllipsis {
    public static void main(String... args) {}
}

$ cat MainArray.java
public class MainArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

After compiling (`javac MainEllipsis.java MainArray.java`), we can check the compiled signatures using `javap -s <class>`:

```
> javap -s MainEllipsis
<...snip...>
  public static void main(java.lang.String...);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

and

```
> javap -s MainArray
<...snip...>
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

`[Ljava/lang/String;` represents the `String[]` type, showing that the generated method signatures are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what others have mentioned, I think this can be useful for writing unit tests of your main() method also.