# Java main methods with "..." arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, string, variadic-functions, ellipsis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the ellipsis (…) for in this method signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367398/what-is-the-ellipsis-for-in-this-method-signature)
>   [java: how can i create a function that supports any number of parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215698/java-how-can-i-create-a-function-that-supports-any-number-of-parameters)

well i'm trying to figure out some examples and I found this kind of array definition for arguments in the main method.
What's so special about this "..." and what's the difference between a normal String[] args?

Thanks

Comment: You probably mean varargs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215698/java-how-can-i-create-a-function-that-supports-any-number-of-parameters

Comment: See this [**post**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2367398/844882) for more info on how elipsis work in Java.

Comment: @Adam, how on earth is "what have you tried" relevant to a question about the meaning of a specific piece of syntax?  (i mean, i think this question should be closed as a dup, but "what have you tried" seems totally irrelevant)

Comment: @KirkWoll Follow the link and read the section starting with "Try taking a few minutes to run through these points:"  The site does far more than just tell you to "try it yourself"; it gives some very good advice for asking effective questions.

Comment: @Adam, I see your point, but in that case, the domain name is particularly unhelpful.  Better would be along the lines of Jon Skeet's ["Writing the perfect question"](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).  No ambiguity and no confusion.  But I concede this isn't your problem. :)

Comment: Thanks for the link -- it'll come in handy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756948/using-ellipsis-in-main-method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a notation from Java 5 for variable length argument lists. It is roughly equivalent to a String array, but lets you pass individual parameters that are combined into an array automatically.

```
void mymethod(String... a) {
    for (String s : a) {
        ...
    }
}

mymethod("quick", "brown", "fox");
```

This makes sense only when you plan to call a method from your program, so I do not see why it would be desirable to use this syntax for your main(). It will work, however.

Answer (score 3):

The elipsis (...) are varargs. They are used when you want to create a method with any number of arguments. Oracle explains how varargs work in detail [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

Answer (score 2):

This is called varargs which means any number of arguments can be passed of that type (`String`).

**1.it should be in final position**

**2.It will be processed as an array**

Answer (score 1):

... is used for varargs.

For example

public void myMethod(Object... params) { 
}

The params variable is optional and is treated as a nullable array of Objects.